# php only appending 3 out of 5 child nodes

Tags: php, xml, dom

This code is only appending 3 of the 5 name nodes. Why is that?
Here is the original XML:
It has 5 name nodes.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<products>
<product>
<itemId>531670</itemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>
<categoryPath>
<category><name>Buy</name></category>
<category><name>Car, Marine &amp; GPS</name></category>
<category><name>Car Installation Parts</name></category>
<category><name>Deck Installation Parts</name></category>
<category><name>Antennas &amp; Adapters</name></category>
</categoryPath>
</product>

</products>
```

Then is run this PHP code. which is suppossed to appened ALL name nodes into the product node.

```
<?php

// load up your XML
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('book.xml');

// Find all elements you want to replace. Since your data is really simple,
// you can do this without much ado. Otherwise you could read up on XPath.
// See http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php
//$elements = $xml->getElementsByTagName('category');

// WARNING: $elements is a "live" list -- it's going to reflect the structure
// of the document even as we are modifying it! For this reason, it's
// important to write the loop in a way that makes it work correctly in the
// presence of such "live updates".


foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('product') as $product ) {
foreach($product->getElementsByTagName('name') as $name ) {
    $product->appendChild($name );
}
$product->removeChild($xml->getElementsByTagName('categoryPath')->item(0));
}

// final result:
$result = $xml->saveXML();
echo $result;
?>
```

The end result is this and it only appends 3 of the name nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
<product>
<itemId>531670</itemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>
<name>Buy</name>
<name>Antennas &amp; Adapters</name>
<name>Car Installation Parts</name>
</product>
</products>
```

Why is it only appending 3 of the name nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily add the `name` elements to an array before appending them, owing to the fact that you're modifying the DOM in real time. The node list generated by `getElementsByTagName()` may change as you are moving nodes around (and indeed that appears to be what's happening).

```
<?php

// load up your XML
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('book.xml');    

// Array to store them
$append = array();
foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('product') as $product ) {
foreach($product->getElementsByTagName('name') as $name ) {
  // Stick $name onto the array
  $append[] = $name;
}
// Now append all of them to product
foreach ($append as $a) {
    $product->appendChild($a);
}

$product->removeChild($xml->getElementsByTagName('categoryPath')->item(0));
}

// final result:
$result = $xml->saveXML();
echo $result;
?>
```

Output, with all values appended:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
<product>
<ItemId>531670</ItemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>

<name>Buy</name><name>Car, Marine &amp; GPS</name><name>Car Installation Parts</name><name>Deck Installation Parts</name><name>Antennas &amp; Adapters</name></product>

</products>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying the DOM tree as you're pulling results from it. Any modifications to the tree that cover the results of a previous query operation (your getElementsByTagName) invalidate those results, so you're getting undefined results. This is especially true of operations that add/remove nodes.

Comment: @Ben, as I said in my answer you need to iterate over the name nodes in reverse.

Comment: I'd suggest building your `<name>` collection in a seperate dom document, then you can use `->importNode()` to insert those into the original document after you've finished iterating/removing the nodes you need to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

You're moving nodes as you're iterating through them so 2 are being skipped.  I'm not a php guy so I can't give you the code to do this, but what you need to do is build a collection of the name nodes and iterate through that collection in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

A less complicated way to do it is to manipulate the nodes with insertBefore

```
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('name') as $node){
    $gp = $node->parentNode->parentNode;
    $ggp = $gp->parentNode;
    // move the node above gp without removing gp or parent
    $ggp->insertBefore($node,$gp);
}
// remove the empty categoryPath node
$ggp->removeChild($gp);
```